# Fill multiple columns with value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill empty columns in one Pandas dataframe with columns from another Pandas dataframe, based on certain conditions.

First table is `audit_records_df` and it looks like this:

| id | audit_type | audit_date | maliciousness_level | suspicious_counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Unknown | 2/5/21 | NaN | NaN |
| 123456 | Cleared | 2/6/21 | NaN | NaN |
| 123456 | Terminated | 2/8/21 | NaN | NaN |
| 345678 | Terminated | 2/5/21 | NaN | NaN |

Second table is `spam_profile_most_recent_notes`:

| id | audit_type | audit_date | maliciousness_level | suspicious_counts | ire_1 | ire_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Unknown | 2/5/21 | high | 3 | 222 | 222 |
| 345678 | Terminated | 2/5/21 | high | 6 | 222 | 222 |

**Note that unlike** `audit_records_df` **table (where an** `id` **could have multiple rows), in** `spam_profile_most_recent_notes` **table each** `id` **will only have 1 row.**

I am trying to fill columns `maliciousness_level` and `suspicious_counts` in `audit_records_df` table with values from columns of the same name from `spam_profile_most_recent_notes` table (we need to ignore columns `ire_1` and `ire_2`), based on the following criteria:

- For rows in `audit_records_df` table where `id` matches `id` in `spam_profile_most_recent_notes`, fill the `maliciousness_level` and `suspicious_counts` in `audit_records_df` table with corresponding values from `spam_profile_most_recent_notes` table in the rows where `id` matches.

After the filling, the `audit_records_df` table should look like this:

| id | audit_type | audit_date | maliciousness_level | suspicious_counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Unknown | 2/5/21 | high | 3 |
| 123456 | Cleared | 2/6/21 | high | 3 |
| 123456 | Terminated | 2/8/21 | high | 3 |
| 345678 | Terminated | 2/5/21 | high | 6 |

I've seen some slightly similar questions like this one: [Conditionally fill column with value from another DataFrame based on row match in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614289/conditionally-fill-column-with-value-from-another-dataframe-based-on-row-match-i). However, all I've seen were regarding filling in value in 1 column, unlike my use case where I have to fill in values for multiple columns.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it not a merge?

Comment: have u checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062176/fill-nan-values-from-another-dataframe-with-different-shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can solve this by:

1. Drop the `malicious_level` and `suspicious_counts` columns from the `audit_record_df` table.
2. Keep only `id`, `malicious_level` and `suspicious_counts` columns from the `spam_profile_most_recent_notes`
3. Perform a left inner join on both tables using `id`

```py
audit_record_df.drop(['maliciousness_level', 'suspicious_counts'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(audit_record_df)

       id  audit_type audit_date
0  123456     Unknown     2/5/21
1  123456     Cleared     2/6/21
2  123456  Terminated     2/8/21
3  345678  Terminated     2/5/21

spam_profile_most_recent_notes = spam_profile_most_recent_notes[['id', 'maliciousness_level', 'suspicious_counts']]
print(spam_profile_most_recent_notes)

       id  audit_type audit_date
0  123456     Unknown     2/5/21
1  123456     Cleared     2/6/21
2  123456  Terminated     2/8/21
3  345678  Terminated     2/5/21

new_df = audit_record_df.merge(spam_profile_most_recent_notes, on='id', how='left')
print(new_df)

       id  audit_type audit_date maliciousness_level  suspicious_counts
0  123456     Unknown     2/5/21                high                  3
1  123456     Cleared     2/6/21                high                  3
2  123456  Terminated     2/8/21                high                  3
3  345678  Terminated     2/5/21                high                  6
```

Comment: Thanks @Safuan. That is one smart approach that I should've thought about, essentially adjusting the columns to make merging work.